# How is access strategy determined in a JPA XML descriptor file?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, metadata

If NO annotation is specified in a class and all metadata is specified in an XML descriptor file, how is the access strategy(field/method) determined?

Comment: By looking at the XSD of that file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the book Pro JPA 2:

> The access element that is defined in the persistence-unit-defaults
>   section is used to set the access type for all the managed classes in
>   the persistence unit that have XML entries but are not annotated. Its
>   value can be either “FIELD” or “PROPERTY”

```
<entity-mappings>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <access>PROPERTY</access>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

The default can be overridden via the access attribute on any entity, mapped-superclass, or embeddable element.